# TexStudio: .pgf files highlight the syntax the same as .tex

Tags: texstudio, syntax-highlighting

I like to generate plots with matplotlib's pgf backend - the output file is .pgf (basically just .tex). I'd like to to keep the file extension as .pgf as it helps me differentiate a figure file. TeXstudio does not recognize the .pgf extension and does not highlight the syntax - is there an option that will tell TeXstudio to highlight .pgf syntax the same as .tex files?